# Git http.proxy Setting

Tags: git, proxy

I was trying to figure this git thing out and at one moment I messed with the http.proxy variable. Right now it's just nonsense, 'asdf' so pushing doesn't work. I don't know what the proxy setting was before (I don't even know what proxy server is). Any way to set http.proxy to the correct value?

Right now the error is: "Couldn't resolve proxy 'asdf' while accessing ... fatal: HTTP request failed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You added an entry to your git config file by mistake. You can manipulate the both the global and per-repository config files using `git config`.

To find out if you added the proxy entry to the global or local config files run this from the console:

```
git config -l --global | grep http  # this will print the line if it is in the global file
git config -l | grep http # this will print the line if it is in the repo config file
```

Then to remove all the `http.proxy` entries from either the global or the local file run this:

```
git config --global --unset-all http.proxy # to remove it from the global config
git config --unset-all http.proxy  # to remove it from the local repo config file
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, I had ProxyCommand set up in ```~/.ssh/config```, which I had to remove on top what @mamapitufo mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The git config file is a local one (ie it is not pushed to a remote repo).
So unless you have some kind of local history/backup mechanism in place (like TimeMachine on Mac), you cannot restore it easily.

On Windows for instance, if you have access to the registry, [you can look for the proxy settings there](https://superuser.com/questions/164365/does-the-registry-location-of-ie-proxy-settings-vary-between-versions-of-ie-and).